# Join over three tables in SQL

Tags: sql, join

How to join in SQL if I want to know which "Mann" belongs to which "Frau"?

The Result should look like:

```
FrauX "id" | MannX "id"
FrauY "id" | MannY "id"
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cv8NM.png]

Answer (score 3):

The join is below, you can select the columns you need for your query

```
SELECT m.idMann
   , m.Name AS MannName
   , f.idFrau 
   , f.Name AS FrauName
FROM Mann AS m
INNER JOIN Frau_has_Mann AS fm ON m.idMann = fm.Mann_idMann
INNER JOIN Frau AS f ON fm.Frau_idFrau = f.idFrau
```

It appears as the aliasing may be causing trouble, can you try:

```
SELECT Mann.idMann
   , Mann.Name AS MannName
   , Frau.idFrau 
   , Frau.Name AS FrauName
FROM Mann
INNER JOIN Frau_has_Mann ON Mann.idMann = Frau_has_Mann.Mann_idMann
INNER JOIN Frau ON Frau_has_Mann.Frau_idFrau = Frau.idFrau
```

basically removing the alias names for whole column name.

Comment: here i get: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'm.idMann' in 'field list'

Comment: There is a syntax error in the code you are running.  To diagnose, remove the 3rd and 4th columns for the select, and just select the two columns from the `Mann table`. If that works, then add the first `inner join`. Again, when that works, add the 2nd `inner join`.  Last, add back the columns `f.idFrau` and `f.Name`

Comment: I have added a query for you without alias names.  Hopefully this will work better for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select F.idFrau,M.idMann FROM Frau AS F INNER JOIN Frau_has_Mann AS FHM ON FHM.Frau_idFrau = F.idFrau INNER JOIN Mann AS M ON M.idMann = FHM.Mann_idMann
```

Hope this is what you are looking for .